# CSS: Does this statement affect both elements of that class

Tags: css

If i have the following CSS:

```
.contactUsDiv label, input { display:block; }
```

Does that mean that ALL labels inside contactUsDiv elements will have block display & that ALL inputs inside the BODY will have block display?

OR

Does it mean that ALL labels AND inputs inside contactUsDiv elements will have block display?

Do I need to do this to get the latter to occur...

```
.contactUsDiv label, .contactUsDiv input { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the latter to limit them both to `.contactUsDiv`. The comma starts a completely new selector.

```
.contactUsDiv label, input { display:block; }
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
.contactUsDiv label { display:block; }
input { display:block; }
```

And

```
.contactUsDiv label, .contactUsDiv input { display:block; }
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
.contactUsDiv label { display:block; }
.contactUsDiv input { display:block; }
```

W3 Specs on this are available here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping

Answer (score 0):

The comma-seperated selectors are completely independent. So if you want to apply that style only to input elements inside of `.contactUsDiv`, you'd have to repeat it, yes.